# TypeError: urlopen() got an unexpected keyword argument 'headers'_Python3

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I was trying to scrape a website for practice with Python 3.6.4, but I keep receiving a `TypeError` for an unexpected keyword argument `headers`.
Does anyone know what is causing the error?

Here is my code:

```
 from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
 url = 'https://www.inside.com.tw'
 headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
 html = urlopen(url, headers=headers).read()
```

The error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: urlopen() got an unexpected keyword argument 'headers'
```

Comment: Did you check the [documentation for [`urllib3.request.urlopen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen)? The function does indeed not take a `headers` argument. But you did import the `Request` class..

Answer (score 5):

The `urllib` module doesn't quite work the same way as the preferred `requests` module. 
Where with `requests` you might use:

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.inside.com.tw'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
html = requests.get(url, headers=headers).content
```

With `urllib`, you need to create a `Request` object, and add your headers to it:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
url = 'https://www.inside.com.tw'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
request = Request(url, headers=headers)
html = urlopen(request).read()
```